# Is there any way in sharepoint to display only the document libraries of that particular site in the home.apx page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, spfx, modern-experience, highlighted-content-web-part

I have to display list of all the document libraries of that SharePoint site in the SharePoint homepage i.e `home.aspx` page.

I there any way to do this, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1: Use Highlighted content web part**:

You can use Highlighted content web part for such scenarios and query your SharePoint site like `ContentClass:"STS_List_DocumentLibrary"` to get the list of document libraries in your site.

[image]

[Use the Highlighted content web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd)

**Solution 2: Create your own SPFx webpart**:

You can create a custom SPFx webpart and use SharePoint REST API or Search API to get the document libraries in your site. Something like below:

```
<your_site_url>/_api/web/lists?$select=Title,ServerRelativeUrl&$filter=BaseTemplate eq 101 and hidden eq false
```

OR

```
<your_site_url>/_api/Web/lists?$select=Title,ServerRelativeUrl&$filter=BaseTemplate eq 101 and Title ne 'Site Assets' and Title ne 'Style Library'
```

**References**:

1. [Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)
2. [How can I list all document libraries under a site using REST API?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/186616/how-can-i-list-all-document-libraries-under-a-site-using-rest-api)

Comment: Thank you so much .This solved my problem.

Comment: Yes, i did that.

Comment: Ganesh, I need your help - it looks like solution 1 no longer works as of today. My post - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/311022/lost-listing-from-contentclasssts-list-documentlibrary

Comment: I just tested and it is still working for me: [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/rIiQzg0). I am using targeted release tenant. which one are you using [standard/targeted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/release-options-in-office-365?view=o365-worldwide)?

Answer (score 0):

1.Use document library web part to show all the document libraries in the homepage.

2.Use quick links web part to list of all the document libraries in the homepage.

Comment: Yes we can use that and it is in manual way .but when a new document library is created,  then i want that also to automatically save in the home page? is this possible?. If yes, then please help me in the issue.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to insert a web part into the homepage automatically.