# How do I acquire a single SharePoint page in PowerQuery?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, site-collection, site-contents, power-query

This page - Site Contents - would be really useful to me:

```
https://......sharepoint.com/sites/....../....../_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx?view=14
```

I want to pull this table into a excel sheet by means of PowerQuery, but when I try "Get Data" from the web address, I'm steered towards using a SharePoint Connector which won't let me access that page.

How else could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to read all lists & libraries in SharePoint site, you can use below endpoint with OData in Power Query:

```
https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists
```

**Reference**: [Working with lists and list items with REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/Working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-REST)

---

**Update**:

To get the desired results, you can apply filters as per your requirements.

**Examples**:

Filter out the hidden lists/libraries like:

```
/_api/web/lists?$filter=Hidden eq false
```

Get only document libraries:

```
/_api/web/lists?$filter=BaseTemplate eq 101
```

Also, you can combine multiple filters like:

```
/_api/web/lists?$filter=BaseTemplate eq 101 and Hidden eq false
```

**Source**: [Is there any way in sharepoint to display only the document libraries of that particular site in the home.apx page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/282752/is-there-any-way-in-sharepoint-to-display-only-the-document-libraries-of-that-pa/282807#282807)

Comment: Thanks, yes you are right. The problem I have with this approach is that whilst it does give me the lists, it also gives me so much other fluff that I end up downloading GBs of data to get hold of the 34kB that I need. That's why I'm asking about the actual page (or view).

Comment: For that you need to apply necessary filters as per your requirements. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Let me clarify.... applying filters, shaves maybe 10kb  off the download of 2Gb

Comment: What if you fetch specific information of lists like: `/_api/web/lists?$select=Title,Description,BaseTemplate&$filter=Hidden eq false` ?

Comment: Hi @Maxcot, did you try above suggestion? did it help you to minimize the data size?

Comment: I did , but it pulls more data than the original.