# Lost listing from contentClass:STS_List_DocumentLibrary

Tags: sharepoint-online, query, kql, kql-query

Within SharePoint Online, I have a page that is making use of the "Highlighted content" web part. Here are my settings for it :

- Custom query is **selected**
- The source is set to "**This site**"
- The Query text (KQL) has the following markup :

  ```
  contentClass:"STS_List_DocumentLibrary"
  title: "Group A"
  ```
- Its sorted by **most recent**
- Enable audience targeting is **off**
- Group-level caching is blank
- Layout is set to **List**
- "Show up this many items at a time" is set to **8**

This web part was working properly last Friday (3 days ago), but as of now (Monday) its showing the following :

[image]

Why would this happen?

It  honestly feels like **contentClass:"STS_List_DocumentLibrary"** has officially stopped working for the Highlighted content web part, as of today.

Comment: I just tested and it is still working for me: [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/rIiQzg0). I am using targeted release tenant. which one are you using [standard/targeted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/release-options-in-office-365?view=o365-worldwide)?

Comment: Thank you so much for confirming that Ganesh!  I looked this morning and now see that one of my many document libraries is responding to STS_List_DocumentLibrary. So odd. I wonder if re-indexing the site would help...

Comment: Yes, you can try re-indexing the site.

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you indicate multiple filters in your search query an `OR` operator is applied. So your filter is in fact: `contentClass:STS_List_DocumentLibrary` OR `Title:"Group A"`. Maybe some new documents were created since your previous test?

Try this instead:
`contentClass:STS_List_DocumentLibrary AND Title:"Group A"`

Comment: Nothing - still the same results.  Everything was fine Friday, and now it does now work...

Comment: Ok :( Maybe you can add more context in your question (which webpart, configuration, etc.)

Comment: Its updated with more details

Answer (score 0):

I had to re-index the SharePoint site.  The files are starting to come back into display with **contentClass:"STS_List_DocumentLibrary** now that a re-index has been initiated.

This is probably good practice to do in such events that appear strange.  Thanks everyone for the help!  I'm just happy that my KQL logic was correct and my content assets are all still there.